# Can't install heroku-accounts plugin in heroku cli

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm trying to install **heroku-accounts** using this command:

`$ heroku plugins:install heroku-accounts`

but instead I got this:

> heroku-cli: Updating plugins... !
>
> /Users/hit/Library/Caches/heroku/update.lock is locked with a reader active: 17964

I try rm the update.lock but it still get same result

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by updating Heroku (I use homebrew install heroku)

`heroku update`

`brew upgrade heroku`

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers seem to work for me. The issue happened when I updated my heroku-cli via brew to version heroku-cli/6.13.8 (darwin-x64) node-v8.2.1 .

Although Error was very explicit that one more process is running, `ps | grep` showed no such process.

The only solution was to **Restart System Once**.

Answer (score 0):

There is another copy of the heroku CLI running with the PID `17964`

You can find it by doing something like this:

```
ps | grep 17964
```

Once you stop that process try your install again.